# php not working properly with html

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
  if(!isset($_SESSION['c_id']) || (!isset($_SESSION['s_id'])))
  {
  ?>
  Login/Register
  <ul>
  <li>
  <a href="register.php">
  Student Login
  </a>
  </li>
  <li>
  <a href="register.php">
  Student Registration
  </a>
  </li>
  <li>
  <a href="company_register.php"">
  Company Login
  </a>
  </li>
  <li>
  <a href="company_register.php">
  Company Registration
  </a>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <?php
  } 
  else
  {
  ?>
  <a href="logout_exec.php>Logout
  </a>
  </li>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
  </ul>
```

This is my code snippet,

When the user is logged in, even then `Logout`is not being displayed, as clear from the post if the SESSION IDs are not set means the user is not logged in, in that case the content pertaining to that condition is being displayed however not the other way round

The login_exec.php file

```
include ("db_conn.php");

function clean_input($data)
{
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = trim($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
//registration form data validation

if(!empty($_POST['Go']))
{
$email= $password= "";
$email= clean_input($_POST['email']);
$pass= clean_input($_POST['pass']);
$pass = hash("sha256", $pass);
$type= $_GET['type'];

global $query;

if($type=="student")
{
$query= "SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE email='$email' AND password='$pass'";
}

elseif($type=="company")
{
$query= "SELECT * FROM COMPANY WHERE email='$email' AND password='$pass'";
}
echo $query;
$query1= mysqli_query($dbhandle,$query);
if(!$query1)
{
echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error();
        exit;
        }

$count= mysqli_num_rows($query1);

if($count==0)
{echo "No Data";
}
else
{
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1))
if($type=="student")
{

session_start();
$_SESSION['sname']= $row['F_Name'].' '.$row['L_Name'];
$_SESSION['s_id']= $row['id'];
header('Location: /Internshala/index.php?s_id='.$_SESSION['s_id']);

}
elseif($type=="company")
{
session_start();
$_SESSION['cname']=$row['Name'];
echo $_SESSION['cname'];
$_SESSION['c_id']=$row['c_id'];
header('Location: /Internshala/index.php?c_id='.$_SESSION['c_id']);
}
}
}
```

Comment: What does your logout script look like?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy it contains a simple session_destroy() for now

Comment: Is there any data printed to the script after the session_destroy();

Comment: @Ohgodwhy No, just a simple redirect to index.php

Comment: Can you try session regenerate ID?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy on the current page?

Comment: Yes. try to use `session_regenerate_id();` on the logout script

Comment: @Ohgodwhy No luck so far

Comment: Your conditional statement is wrong

Comment: @CodingHorror Like maybe && instead of || right? and an extra )

Comment: The question that hasn't been asked, so I'll ask it: Is `session_start();` inside all pages using sessions? It's not mentioned nor shown in your code.

Comment: How are both session variables being set? You're only showing us a conditional statement. That's not enough to go on.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of all your files right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. My guess is, you might get a warning.

Comment: You also should add `exit;` after all your header.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The statement throws an error  syntax error, unexpected 'error_reporting' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\Internshala\index.php on line 2

Comment: You may not have copied that correctly. `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest  of your code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Made an identical copy, still the same error.

Comment: Also <?php
  }
  
  ?>

In the end of the condition the ?> is not matching with <?php in IDE, if you know what I mean

Comment: Are you sure your server's properly setup? Do `<?php echo "Hello world";`

Comment: Ok, you're going in and out of PHP. Just do `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>` with a closing tag, then the rest of your code that you're using. That shouldn't throw the same error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No errors were logged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally...

If using OR operator , then even if one of the SESSION variables are not set, the script will display everything except else's block.

And even after using the AND operator when Coding Horror suggested that the if(condition) is wrong, it won't work. But while discussing with Fred ii, I noticed the **mismatch between `<?php and ?>`** towards the end, which finally made me discover **a missing "** here `<a href="logout_exec.php>Logout`. So this was the reason for the havoc.

All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if with session is empty or not like

```
 if(empty($_SESSION['c_id']) || !isset($_SESSION['c_id']))
 {
   //after not login
 } 
 else
 {
   //after login
 }
```

Comment: Still not working and I figured there would be a binary multiplication i.e && in the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['c_id']) || !empty($_SESSION['c_id']))
{
     //Login here
} 
else
{
    //Please Login
 }
```

Comment: Why next time, you can update your answer this time. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if( !isset($_SESSION['c_id']) || !isset($_SESSION['s_id']) )
  {
    //after not login
  }
  else {

         //after login
  }
```

try this